# Binding Custom Button Background/ Border to Custom Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am fairly new to WPF and the .NET Framework.

I have created a custom button class and have added a dependency property "Colors" which is another class that I created which defines a buttons  border/face colors when enabled and disabled. In the style for this button, I am trying to use Relative Source Binding to Bind members of the "Colors" property to different Properties of the button (Border.Background, Border.BorderBrush, etc.).

Here is my button class:

```
public class FsnButton : Button
{
    static FsnButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FsnButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FsnButton)));
    }

    public FsnButton()
    {
        Colors = FsnColors.GrayBtnColors;
    }

    public GuiTypes.ButtonColors Colors
    {
        get { return GetValue(ColorsProperty) as GuiTypes.ButtonColors; }
        set { SetValue(ColorsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Colors", typeof(GuiTypes.ButtonColors), typeof(FsnButton), null);
}
```

And here is the template portion of the style

```
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:FsnButton">
                <Border Name="Face" CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{ Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Colors.Enabled.Face}" 
                        BorderThickness="1" 
                        BorderBrush="{ Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Colors.Enabled.Border}">
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Colors.Enabled.Border}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="DarkSlateGray" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5"></DropShadowEffect>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform X="3" Y="3" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
```

This approach is unsuccessful. When I create an instance of my button class, It doesn't get drawn at all. Am I on the right path? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Your binding paths doesn't resolve. You have to use either `TemplateBinding` or `RelativeSoure TemplatedParent`, whenever you are inside a `ControlTemplate` and want to bind to the templated control itself:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:FsnButton">

  <!-- TemplatedParent binding source -->
  <Border Name="Face"  
          Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Colors.Enabled.Face}"
          BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Colors.Enabled.Border}" />

  <!-- TemplateBinding -->
  <Border Name="Face"  
          Background="{TemplateBinding Colors.Enabled.Face}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Colors.Enabled.Border}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```